# performance improvements for my hashmap implementation

Tags: performance, go, hash, hashmap, bit-manipulation

I decided i'd try make my own hashmap ([here](https://github.com/robert-king/my-hash-map/blob/master/hashmap/hash_map.go))

For reads it's 28% slower than the standard library implementation, I'm wondering if it's possible to speed up the following code, **Index()** which is critical for lookups:

```
const numOnes = uint8(20)
const ones = uint32(1 << numOnes - 1)

func (m *Map) Index(num uint64) uint32 {
    part := uint32(num) & ones
    remaining := num >> numOnes
    start := m.starts[part]
    bitsNum := m.bitNums[part]
    matchedBits := bitsNum & uint16(remaining)
    offset := BitScoreCache[bitsNum][matchedBits]
    return start + uint32(offset)
}
```

note BitScoreCache is `var BitScoreCache [5000][5000]uint16` which is supposed to be readonly and be shared between multiple different map instances.

example usage:

```
func (pa PrimeAdvancedAnagrammar) GetAnagrams(word string) []string {
    return pa.m[pa.locator.Index(PrimeProduct(word))] //pa.m is an [][]string
}
```

versus standard library:

```
func (pba PrimeBasicAnagrammar) GetAnagrams(word string) []string {
    return pba.m[PrimeProduct(word)] //pba.m is a map[uint64][]string
}
```

What are the main reasons it's slower than the standard library for so few operations?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Tl7mi9QmLns

Comment: Well, the builtin map implementation is pretty fundamental for Go so it is heavily optimised. Optimizing something is a hard problem. E.g. your BitScoreCache is pretty large and lookups in there are not cache friendly (which might be a bottleneck albeit it looks innocent).

Comment: Off-topic because this question belongs on another site: [codereview](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: You might try making `BitScoreCache` "one-dimensional", so the runtime only has to check one index: `var BitScoreCache [5000*5000]uint16`; and index it like `BitScoreCache[bitsNum*5000+matchedBits]`.

Comment: To expand on @Volker's point, [a performance improvement to go map implementation](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/ec091b6af2ad6f33f3b36c39171d7ef65b12668b) was added a few days ago. It appears to use the compiler to choose a fast path.

Comment: Another [performance improvement to go map implementation](https://github.com/golang/go/commit/5d6b7fcaa1444f6c17d519c9ce7bc0771bfd96ec)

Answer (score 0):

Combining the two arrays into one array of structs reduced cache misses and was the biggest performance improvement.

also returning early on the case that there is no collisions improved performance.